# OddSum Recursion exercise, dont know how to make the sum

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class OddSum {

    public static int oddSum(int n) {

        int totalSum;

        if (n % 2 != 0 && n > 0) {
            totalSum = totalSum + n;
            System.out.println(totalSum);
            return oddSum(n - 1);
            //System.out.println(totalSum);
            //return 1;
        } else {
            if (n == 0) {
                System.out.println(totalSum);
                return totalSum;
            } else {
                return oddSum(n - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        oddSum(13);
    }
}
```

Im a bit confused, if I assign totalSum = 0 then it just resets to zero every time the recursive method runs, im trying to sum all the odd numbers, its in the think java book, public and private variables havent been introduced yet.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325974/recursive-algorithm-for-the-sum-of-odd-number-positive-integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for

```
public static int oddSum(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (n % 2 != 1) ? oddSum(n - 1) : oddSum(n - 1) + n;
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

As you have already noticed, it's not recommendable to assign the totalSum to some value inside the recursive method since it will just be reset every time the method runs. What you do instead is

- define a *base case*, which is `if (n == 1)` in this case. The recursion stops here and `1` is returned as a result (because it's the smallest odd number > 0)
- define a *recursion step* `return (n % 2 != 1) ? oddSum(n - 1) : oddSum(n - 1) + n` that is called everytime the method has not yet reached the *base case*. In this step you apply your condition `n % 2 != 1` and check whether the number is even or odd. If `n` is even, you just call the method with the next smaller number `oddSum(n - 1)`. Otherwise - if `n` is odd - you still call the method with the next smaller number, but this time you add the value of the odd `n` to it: `oddSum(n - 1) + n`.

Comment: `int n = 13;`


`System.out.println("Total sum of odd numbers in [0," /* more specific */ + n + "] is: " + oddSum(n));`